# Trying to add another location directive in an nginx server with proxy cache

Tags: nginx, location, directive

I have a website with a couple of pages and images and I have setup an nginx server to handle the website. When I add a location directive to handle the images, the entire website does not show up and look broken.

The website looks perfect when the bottom of my nginx file looks like this:

```
    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    #location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    #   proxy_cache sinuscache;
    #   add_header Pragma public;
    #   add_header Cache-Control "public";
    #   expires 1d;
    #   log_not_found off;
    #}      

    location ~* (\.bak|\.off|\.config|\.exe|\.sql|\.fla|\.psd|\.ini|\.log|\.sh|\.inc|\.swp|\.dist)$ {
        deny all;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        expires -1d;
        access_log off;
    }

   location / {
      include              /etc/nginx/sites-settings/denyips.conf;
      proxy_pass           http://127.0.0.1:9099;
      proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_cache          sinuscache;
   }
}
```

When I un-comment

```
    #location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    #   proxy_cache sinuscache;
    #   add_header Pragma public;
    #   add_header Cache-Control "public";
    #   expires 1d;
    #   log_not_found off;
    #}
```

The website breaks. If I do a

```
service nginx configtest
```

I receive no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `location` block is incomplete - as a minimum you will want to include `proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9099;` and probably many of the other statements from the `location /` block. See [how `nginx` processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Some of the statements can be placed into the `server` block to avoid replication. For example:

```
proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_cache          sinuscache;

location / {
    include              /etc/nginx/sites-settings/denyips.conf;
    proxy_pass           http://127.0.0.1:9099;
}
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    include              /etc/nginx/sites-settings/denyips.conf;
    proxy_pass           http://127.0.0.1:9099;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    expires 1d;
    log_not_found off;
}
```